# How to take leaves as a Visiting Researcher?

Tags: germany, visa, travel, visiting

I am a PhD student employed by a German university, and I am in the middle of a six-month J1 visa in the US as a visiting researcher in another university, still paid by my German employer.

Those six months are considered as a business trip, which means that I get daily allowances to cover for the difference of life price between Germany and the US. This also means that I can not take days off officially for six months (although I have plenty of days off left to take).

I want to travel home to Germany for 10 days to visit a sick relative, see family I couldn't see because of COVID, and handle the apartment I sublet.

I brought this up to my German supervisor in an email but he did not react to this specific point. I can just ask my advisor in the host university but I can not go without telling anything to my German supervisor...

Edit:

- My visa allows me to go back to Germany for a couple of days.
- German federal reimbursement rules typically forbid business travel being combined with vacations longer than 3 day.

**My Question:**

The administration told me I can not take vacation because it is a business trip. But not letting me take vacations for 6 months although I earned them is quite a precarious situation. **Is it legitimate for me to require some vacations and with what lever can I negociate?**

Comment: Isn't this more of a visa question than anything? Would the Workplace be a better place to ask? https://workplace.stackexchange.com/

Comment: A J1 visa does not allow you to take vacation days?

Comment: Is the daily allowance relevant?

Comment: Are you asking about the implications for your visa of returning to Germany from the US while on a J1 visa, or are you asking about the interpersonal aspect of informing/getting permission from your German and US supervisors? And on what basis/whose authority do you state that you "can not take days off officially for six months"?

Comment: @Buffy Most J1 visitors are going to be in academic settings, I don't see a connection to Workplace. Possibly https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/ would be appropriate for visa issues.

Comment: I suggest the travel stack.

Comment: Who's rule is it that you can't take days off for a while??  Since you'd like to take days off when the terms (I can't tell whether those terms come from your home Uni, your host uni, or your visa) tell you that you can't, I'd start with whoever that rule came from

Comment: As long as the J-1 visa isn't restricted to single entry or otherwise expired it seems the immigration part should be straight-forward. As for the reimbursement issues that's something to discussed with your home institution.

Comment: I suppose the problem is that the visit is being financed as a business trip by the German employer. German federal reimbursement rules typically forbid business travel being combined with vacations longer than 3 days. If this is the case the OP should clarify this.

Comment: @TimRias Indeed. It is not a visa problem, as my visa allows me to go home. It is more of an administrative problem. I think my advisors don't mind if I take days off, but if it goes through the German university administration, they will forbid it.

Comment: @MaiKar Are you getting your per diem in advance, or will you be claiming it afterwards?

Comment: @MaiKar Can you please update your question to be what you are specifically asking this site for help with? If your supervisors are fine with your vacation, your visa is fine for you to leave and re-enter the country, but your German university will forbid it no matter what (for reasons still unclear to me), what's the problem you want help with?

Comment: "This also means that I can not take days off officially for six months" If this prevents you from taking the legal annual vacation minimum or even more so if this causes vacation entitlement to expire, it might not be legal.

Comment: Can't you just formally interrupt the business trip? Just have the German university handle it as two 3-month trips with a gap in between instead of a 6-month one. I assume that should be perfectly legal even in Germany.

Comment: I realize that rules in Germany can be pretty strict, but isn't there a humanitarian exception for such things? I would guess that there must be.

Comment: @TooTea Maybe this is an option actually. But if they split my business trip in two, they are theoretically supposed to pay for my flight back and forth.
Maybe I can negociate on this base: split my trip but no need to pay for the flight for my week off.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience it's all a matter of a gentleman's agreement between you, your supervisor from the home institution and your supervisor from the host institution.

Usually they only want you to get the job done. If you do everything in one month, you can have a five months holiday. I exaggerate just a bit.

Best answer is to just ask both your bosses.

Comment: Indeed, I finally did that. US boss agrees, I'm waiting to see what German boss says as this is the tricky side.